# How to fix Firebase notification issue while in background mode

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

When my Ionic app is in foreground, notification arrives perfectly.

When my Ionic app is in background, the Firebase push notification displays the a system tray notification. Pressing the banner opens the app and the notification fires. I am completely fine with that.

But, if user decides to open the app without clicking the banner, the notification doesn't trigger. Anytime clicking the banner results into the arrival of the notification into the app.

How can I resolve this situation? How can I make the notification fire, regardless of whether the app is clicked from notification tray or normally?

Edit:

The firebase [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) I'm sending looks like this :

```
   {
  "data":{
    "fieldA":"A",
    "fieldB" : "B",
    "fieldC" : "C",
    "total" : 1234,
    "title" : "_my_title",
    "message" : "_my_message",
    "sound" : "default",
    "cick_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  },
    "to":"/topics/MY_TOPIC",
    "priority":"high"
}
```

Comment: try it in different phone maybe this problem just in this phone version

Comment: same problem here. did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the notification you send is of type data message, not display messages.

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
>   These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
>
> Data messages, which
>   are handled by the client app.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Also

> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the
>   notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps
>   on the notification. When in the foreground, your app receives a
>   message object with both payloads available.

And

> To receive messages, use a service that extends
>   FirebaseMessagingService. Your service should override the
>   onMessageReceived and onDeletedMessages callbacks.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Edited my original question. I am sending data message. The problem still persists - if the app is in the foreground, the data payload is received immediately; if the app is in background, only clicking the notification tray opens the app and triggers the data payload.

Comment: "When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification. When in the foreground, your app receives a message object with both payloads available." - isn't this applicable for type "Notification messages" only? Or is it applicable for "Data messages" too?